# SharePoint - Messed Up Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, css, layouts

I was editing one of the web pages I created. Just one of many, in SharePoint Designer, and after dragging the edge of what I thought was just a table cell (td) all pages no longer display all the text on the page. It cuts it off at about 60 px.
All the text and images and web parts show up in the edit view, but disappear when just look the pages.
Even making a new page does the same thing.
I am boggled..no idea what I did:( It looks like I edited something on the master page, or CSS, but I really do not understand it well enough to figure it out and restoring an old version does not work.
[image: This is the content in Edit Mode]

[image: THis is the content when saved and displaying the page.]

Comment: What page did you modify? Edit your question and then post a comment.

Comment: It was just one of the pages I have created in the "site pages" folder. Not the homepage or default.